How to convert Firestore collection into regular array in VueFire/VueJS 3.0?
I'm new to the whole Firebase scene with Vue3 (and got started using VueFire yesterday)...
I dont know if this is a very specific use-case but I've been using PrimeVue's PickList component. This component needs a multidimensional array as the v-model. So far so good!
My issue is that i'm fetching the items in the picklist from a Firestore (using VueFire) like so:
const mealsCollection = useCollection(collection(db, 'meals'))

I've tested in the console and everything is outputting normally..
Where I am struggling with is HOW do i take the contents of this mealsCollection and put this inside a 2d array.
What i've tried:
const tempMandSlist = ref({
    tempMandSlist: [mealsCollection.value, shortlistedMealsArray]
})

This seems to work, but then I get a warning in the console:
[Vue warn]: onMounted is called when there is no active component instance to be associated with. Lifecycle injection APIs can only be used during execution of setup(). If you are using async setup(), make sure to register lifecycle hooks before the first await statement. 
      at <TransitionGroup ref="targetList" id="pv_id_1_target_list" name="p-picklist-flip"  ... > 
      at <PickList modelValue= (2) [Array(6), Array(5)] onUpdate:modelValue=fn listStyle="height:342px"  ... > 
      at <MealsListComponent> 
      at <HomeView> 
      at <App>

Is there a trick i'm missing in terms of converting the reactive reference that VueFire generates (mealsCollection) and using its contents as a regular array? Normally I thought we used the ref.value notation to access its contents?
I had similar issues fetching mealsCollection.value and assigning the contents to an array inside Pinia. Again console testing showed that i am successfully getting Firestore contents into my app - but where i'm hitting a brick wall is doing something using the collection that Firestore has returned.
Any help appreciated!
